# Search Unique Tag Name

Tags: c#, wordpress-rest-api

I have one array of tags and need to check if the tag already exists in database.

The below code works well, however , `queryBuilder.Search = t[i].Name` works the same way as the LIKE in SQL. I mean, if I have too similar tags, ex "first tag is the best" and "first tag" will get error.

How to use the `queryBuilder.Search` to get exact match?

```
var queryBuilder = new TagsQueryBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < t.Count(); i++)
{
    queryBuilder.Search = t[i].Name;

    var tags = await client.Tags.Query(queryBuilder);

    if (tags.Count() == 0) //If none in BD
    {
        var createdTag = await client.Tags.Create(t[i]);

        t[i].Id = createdTag.Id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I get it [WordPressPCL](https://github.com/wp-net/WordPressPCL) does not support it, but you can inherit from TagsQueryBuilder:

```
public class ExtendedTagsQueryBuilder : TagsQueryBuilder
{
  [QueryText("exact")]
  public bool Exact { get; set; }
}
```

And specify this parameter:

```
 ExtendedTagsQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new ExtendedTagsQueryBuilder();
 queryBuilder.Exact = true;
 queryBuilder.Search = t[i].Name;
 ...
```

Comment: Hi Access Denied, many thanks for your help. Seems better, but I still have some issues... but maybe in other place. I need to check better.